# Control a table column content

Tags: tables, data-tables

Did you ever saw or designed a way to switch column content through its column header?
I've done this before for units or switching between numbers and percentage, but this time its a less obvious switching...

In the below example I used a dropdown so the user can select to see his spendings as '% of total budget' or as '% of the Leisure and Culture budget'.

Is a dropdown (with single selection) is the way to go? or would you use a more prominent control above the table (I have a fairly limited space in the real life design)?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason not to display both at the same time?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles, its very information heavy. The example is simplistic... We are listing Health diagnosis or Medication names along with its usage in the Hospital... I am also suspect that it will cause a comparison between numbers which is irrelevant...however it might be a good option. Will have to check with users for sure.

Comment: That helps. Bear with me... Are users in either "Total Budget" mindset OR in "Leisure and Culture" mindset, but not likely needing both?

Comment: How many items will the select dropdown have?

Comment: Be aware that an arrow in column context is often used to show/change the sorting order. This dropdown arrow can be confusing. In fact I had to read the question to know it wasn't for sorting.

Comment: @Devin two...but long in label, so segmented button will not do unless I use a vertical toggle like suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than not show one or the other column, **use abbreviated column labels** to reduce space:

[image: abbreviated column labels]

Mousing-over the column label displays a **popup** that presents the full column label:

[image: abbreviated column popup]

---

*If displaying one column at a time is necessary*, one option is to use a column label toggle control to switch between columns:

[image: column toggle]

The benefit here is that the alternative column label is not hidden.

If the label is scrolled out of view a mouseover or right click can bring up the toggle control to 1) switch columns, and 2) remind the user what column is displayed:

[image: column toggle menu]

Comment: Thanks @bloodyKnuckles! I have never seen such column label toggle. We will eventually use a dropdown option I think :-(